# Recursion Recursion Recursion --- How can i Improve Performance? (Python Archive Recursive Extraction)

Tags: python, recursion, extract, generator, archive

I am trying to develop a Recursive Extractor. The problem is , it is Recursing Too Much (Evertime it found an archive type) and taking a performance hit.

So how can i improve below code?

My Idea 1:

Get the 'Dict' of direcories first , together with file types.Filetypes as Keys. Extract the file types. When an Archive is found Extract only that one. Then Regenerate Archive Dict again.

My Idea 2:

os.walk returns Generator. So is there something i can do with generators? I am new to Generators.

here is the current code :

```
import os, magic
m = magic.open( magic.MAGIC_NONE )
m.load()

archive_type = [ 'gzip compressed data',
        '7-zip archive data',
        'Zip archive data',
        'bzip2 compressed data',
        'tar archive',
        'POSIX tar archive',
        'POSIX tar archive (GNU)',
        'RAR archive data',
        'Microsoft Outlook email folder (>=2003)',
        'Microsoft Outlook email folder']

def extractRecursive( path ,archives):
    i=0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk( path ):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join( dirpath, f )
            i+=1
            print i
            file_type = m.file( fp ).split( "," )[0]
            if file_type in archives:
                arcExtract(fp,file_type,path,True)
                extractRecursive(path,archives)
    return "Done"



def arcExtract(file_path,file_type,extracted_path="/home/v3ss/Downloads/extracted",unlink=False):
    import subprocess,shlex


    if file_type in pst_types:
        cmd = "readpst -o  '%s' -S '%s'" % (extracted_path,file_path)
    else:
        cmd = "7z -y -r -o%s x '%s'" % (extracted_path,file_path)

    print cmd
    args= shlex.split(cmd)
    print args

    try:
        sp = subprocess.Popen( args, shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
        out, err = sp.communicate()
        print out, err
        ret = sp.returncode
    except OSError:
        print "Error no %s  Message %s" % (OSError.errno,OSError.message)
        pass

    if ret == 0:
        if unlink==True:
            os.unlink(file_path)
        return "OK!"
    else:
        return "Failed"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractRecursive( 'Path/To/Archives' ,archive_type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as it appears, you want to extract the archive files to paths "above" the one they're in, `os.walk` per se (in its normal top-down operation) can't help you (because by the time you extract an archive into a certain directory x, os.walk may likely, though not necessarily, already considered directory x -- so only by having os.walk look at the whole path over and over again can you get all contents).  Except, I'm surprised your code ever terminates, since the archive-type files should keep getting found and extracted -- I don't see what can ever terminate the recursion.  (To solve that it would suffice to keep a set of all the paths of archive-type files you've already extracted, to avoid considering them again when you meet them again).

By far the best architecture, anyway, would be if `arcExtract` was to return a list of all the files it has extracted (specifically their destination paths) -- then you could simply keep extending a list with all these extracted files during the `os.walk` loop (no recursion), and then keep looping just on the list (no need to keep asking the OS about files and directories, saving lots of time on that operation too) and producing a new similar list. No recursion, no redundancy of work.  I imagine that `readpst` and `7z` are able to supply such lists (maybe on their standard output or error, which you currently just display but don't process) in some textual form that you could parse to make it into a list...?

Comment: Yes you may wonder how it may stop,But it stops because of THIS :

in arcExtract:
        if unlink==True:
            os.unlink(file_path)

Which removes archives after un-archiving.

Recursing is Needed Because There are Archives , Inside Archives , Imagine tar.gz and tar.bz2 , they all need to be recursivly extracted. Also PST files contains attachments which have archives , THEY all needed to be extracted.

Comment: Your suggested architecture is feasible. I will try it. The only problem is readpst do not output the extracted folder path. I may able to force it on -o"Path_To_Extract" option but it needs to check for existing folder names first to prevent collision.

Comment: @V3ss, thanks for clarifying why it stops (i.e., due to the removal after unarchiving) and for seeing that the appropriate iteration (if you can get the extracted files' paths) can indeed remove the need for recursion (despite the arch-inside-arch issue, which I had indeed already considered) -- good luck with making readpst do what you need (sounds like a problem for superuser.com;-).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `extractRecursive` method to use `os.walk` as it should be used. `os.walk` already reads all subdirectories so your recursion is unneeded.

Simply remove the recursive call and it should work :)

```
def extractRecursive(path, archives, extracted_archives=None):
    i = 0
    if not extracted_archives:
        extracted_archives = set()

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            i += 1
            print i
            file_type = m.file(fp).split(',')[0]
            if file_type in archives and fp not in extracted_archives:
                extracted_archives.add(fp)
                extracted_in.add(dirpath)
                arcExtract(fp, file_type, path, True)

    for path in extracted_in:
        extractRecursive(path, archives, extracted_archives)

    return "Done"
```

Comment: Recursive call is Needed BECAUSE this is Multi level Archive extraction . For example , lets say we have 50 archives which may contain archives such tar.gz and tar.bz2 , which is tar archive inside bz2 archive, The function need to extract tar from bz2 archive first, then extract tar archive again. and 7z is only choice i get (it dont do automatically like in tar) .

Here what it does is , it extract the bz2 , then recurse into loop, to find the tar file it extracted again . which take extra performance especially when the file is in the middle of the list.

Comment: @V3ss0n: I see. In that case you have 2 options. 1. What Alex Martelli suggested, a clean but possibly more difficult solution.
2. a 1-n running loop where you keep running until no new archives are found. This would require you to keep track of the extracted archives but is fairly easy to implement.

Comment: WoLpH , can you clarify more on your 2nd idea?

Comment: @V3ss0n: I've added an example. It's not that pretty but it should work without recursing infinitely.